# How to change background of Altair plot in VSCode

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have a plot created using pandas and altair using the following code in VSCode

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X("fertility"),
    alt.Y("cluster")
)
```

How do I change the background colour? I'd rather like the background white or off-white.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to change the theme with `alt.themes.enable('default')` as in https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#chart-themes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain it with [`configure_view`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/configuration.html#config-view) :

```
np.random.seed(123456)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "fertility": np.random.uniform(0, 9, 100), "cluster": np.random.randint(0, 6, 100)}
)

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X("fertility"), alt.Y("cluster")).configure_view(fill="white")

#pip install altair_viewer
chart.show() #or chart (in VSCode)
```

Output :

[image]